# 200 as response status code but 4xx error in the response body?

Tags: python, rest, http, http-status-codes

I'm using ArcGIS REST API and I'm testing if I can create a point on the map with invalid token.

I pass all correct data except for token, I pass it as:

```
token = None
```

or

```
token = "randomstring"
```

What I receive as response is status code 200 and in the body of response:

```
{"error":{"code":498,"message":"Invalid token.","details":["Invalid token."]}}
```

I'm wondering if this is "bad" implementation?

Should it return 498 (ArcGIS way of saying 401 I think) as a status code?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? That the implementation is not best practice? Well then it is one of all the APIs out there that is not perfectly implemented.

Comment: It's just a matter of opinion.  I prefer the real HTTP status code is returned, as do most others I've talked to, but because there is no set REST guideline that people adhere to it's just a matter of preference.  For this API you'll just have to look at the `error.code` for the status.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was just looking for opinion on this, if it's a bug or just dev/team preference, wasn't sure about it. I guess I will look for both, response status code and error code in the body.